# asp.net dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am adding items to dropdownlist using addrange method, here is my code

```
ListItem[] cou =
new ListItem[8]{"India",
                "United States",
                "United Kingdom",
                "Canada",
                "Singapore",
                "Australia",
                "Sudia Arabia",
                "South Africa" };
dpcountry.Items.AddRange(cou);
```

but it gives me error as cannot implicitly convert string ti listitem

please give me a solution

thanks in advance
sangita

Comment: Can you atleast accept one answer in your previous 7 questions?

Answer (score 3):

You need to create new ListItems

try

```
string[] cou =new string[8]{
              "India",
              "United States",
              "United Kingdom",
              "Canada",
              "Singapore",
              "Australia",
              "Sudia Arabia",
              "South Africa" };
dpcountry.Items.AddRange(cou.Select(c => new ListItem(c));
```

You will need a reference to System.Linq too,

Kindness,

Dan

Answer (score 2):

I tried Dan's example, but had to add .ToArray() to get it to work, ie:

```
string[] cou =new string[8]{
              "India",
              "United States",
              "United Kingdom",
              "Canada",
              "Singapore",
              "Australia",
              "Saudi Arabia",
              "South Africa" };

dpcountry.Items.AddRange(cou.Select(c => new ListItem(c)).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   object []cou = new object[]{"India",
                               "United States",
                               "United Kingdom",
                               "Canada",
                               "Singapore",
                               "Australia",
                               "Sudia Arabia",
                               "South Africa" };
    dpcountry.Items.AddRange(cou);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating an array of type ListItem, but you are trying to add strings to this array. That is why you get this error. To get this code to work, you should change it to:

`new ListItem[8]{ new ListItem("India"), new ListItem("United"), /* etcetera */ };`